# Does it make sense to play folk music by yourself on the violin?

Tags: practice, violin, folk

I played the violin as a child, and now I'm trying to pick it up again. However, most of the music and notes I have are for classical music, which is what I played back then. So for instance I have been working on Franz Wohlfahrt's "Sixty Studies for the Violin" under the assumption that it is useful no matter what I will end up playing.

However, I really like the sound of bands like [Pentangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentangle_(band)) and [Ygdrassil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ygdrassil_(musical_group)), usually described as folk with jazz/rock/blues influences. These two groups don't use the violin a lot, but for example in [Open the Door](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mnBwg2r0d4) of the Pentangle the violin is somewhat prominent.

I'm definitely not ready to play with others yet, and we're quarantined due to COVID-19 now anyway, so my question is: is there any way I could learn to play this kind of music on the violin that makes sense to do on my own? Or is the violin simply not suited for this and should I stick to another genre / try the guitar (for example) instead / wait for times to improve to join a band where I could have a more supporting role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  Get tabs and practice what kind of double stops on a lower string make for a good fit with the chord symbols written above the melody line (which you also play).  That's way what contributes to a folksy sound and much material to play from will be in the form melody+chords.  So it's a pretty useful skill to not need written-out double stops for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think there's a lot of fun to be had playing folk music solo on the violin - a lot of British/European folk music contains double-stops, and melodies with a strong emphasis on chord tones, that mean the violin part carries the chord progression — and likewise the rhythmic feel of folk violin means that you can play up a storm in the kitchen on your own (or with the people you are self-isolating with!)

Answer (score 1):

There’s a huge tradition of violin (often aka fiddle) music in the various British folk musics and in many other traditional musics worldwide. Pentangle and Ygdrassil are as good a starting point as any, and you’ll be preparing yourself for a lifetime of happy & & fulfilling playing if you put the starting work in now.

Comment: I found out about the 'aka fiddle' bit (and the fact that I should refer to songs as 'tunes') earlier today, and this has indeed opened a whole new world :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a great idea! And there are tons of public domain tune books online. One thing to consider is some folk music uses [alternate tunings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_tuning). Maybe some of the music you like uses such tunings. Or, you might be curious to try it out. I can't play violin, but I get by on guitar. I've tried alternate guitar tunings and it's a nice way to get a fresh view on the instrument. Helps you think a bit deeper about standard tuning.